# Drupal 7: How do I add custom field info to my page?

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Drupal 7 question. What's the best way to display my values for custom fields onto a page?

I know there's the Manage Display, which is great for sorting information, but I'd like to add lots of styling to these values, place them all over the page in different places, and also use some of them multiple times. Sometimes I'd even like to use values inside other values (like adding field1 and field2 and displaying the sum, or making a field clickable to go to a URL designated in another field).

I've looked at things like Display Suite, but that's more for the whole page. I only need to adjust what shows up in the main content area. It also doesn't seem to do what I need to do.

My themes I've used seem to add variables inside the page code (the .tpl files) and display information that way.

What I've been doing is using some of the included variables (like print $date; and print $time;) and have been calling them directly using PHP and the complex array system revealed by devel.

For example, if I want to show body content, I do this:

```
$myContent .= "Body: ".$content['body']['#items'][0]['value'];
```

It works, but I have a feeling there's a better way. If so, what? I haven't yet found it, since I'm looking for something which gives me the most control over how I display the variables for each node type.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to create your own theme for this and then you can potentially override the `field--field_name.tpl.php` file for your field. Check https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming .

Comment: @apokryfos, thanks. I'm doing that already. I have my tpl files and they're working well. My question is about how I add those variables to my tpl file. Is there a way to do this that works well, or is my approach the best we have?

Comment: @apokryfos And I'm asking about the best way to display these custom fields values.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best approach. I just have those .tpl files and some `preprocess_field` in the `template.php` to preprocess the variables for showing. Don't know if its the best thing to do but I think this is more or less what can easily be done in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/node/1375160

https://www.drupal.org/node/1795314

https://www.drupal.org/node/1433006

you have several post related on this...